# SafariLauncher app for Test automation on iOS real device on safari using Appium necessary?

Tags: mobile-safari, appium

I am starting with Safari browser test automation using Appium on real iOS device. I want to launch Safari browser on  my device from appium code. I tried to search for options on net. Most of the posts suggest to use an app SafariLauncher. Does it means that - I cannot launch safari directly in my device using appium ? Why I cannot launch safari from Appium ? I am from Test Automation team and we do not have the developers certificate to resign this SafariLauncher app. Is there any easier way of doing it ?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I achieved it. Basically everything is documented in appium documentation. Following each step from documentation made it work. http://appium.io/slate/en/master/?ruby#automating-mobile-web-apps

However I required the apple developer subscription to resign the safari launcher app.